# Gannt Chart in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts, gantt

I'm trying to create a Gantt chart in Microsoft Excel that will show planned vs. actual project timelines. I started off with this tutorial:

https://www.smartsheet.com/blog/gantt-chart-excel

Which gave me a decent looking Gantt chart to start with. But I'd like to show planned versus actual on the same graph, so I went looking for a more detailed tutorial. I found a few that suggested plotting the 'planned' values on one axis and the 'actual' values on another axis, but whenever I try to do this, the planned values will not display correctly. I've asked coworkers, but no one is quite sure about what else to try.

I'd like to end up with something that looks like the bottom chart in this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595560/excel-gantt-chart-planned-vs-actual

Here is the excel file I'm working with now:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rWnvPVeBaip5UKUf-93wKIjYoA40GvkV/view?usp=sharing

I'd essentially like to combine the green and red charts for each table onto one chart.

Any chart wizards have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Your file link does not work. It says I need permission.

Comment: So sorry! I didn't realize Google defaulted to only sharing that file with people at my company. I've enabled sharing and stripped any confidential information from the file.